# I'm having issues with double quotes and the eval command

Tags: linux, eval

I am using a Linux command that shrinks a pdf using ghostscript from 100% zoom to 90% zoom.  This command works properly from the Linux prompt:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=sam1.pdf -c "<< /BeginPage{0.9 0.9 scale 30.6 39.6 translate}>> setpagedevice" -sPAPERSIZE=letter -dCompatibilityLevel="1.3" -dPDFSETTINGS="/printer" -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -f 2138WH.pdf
```

However, I'm trying to code this into a call from their ERP software (running on a SCO box) that needs to run the code on the Linux box.  I'm struggling with the quotes, double quotes, etc.  I've tried putting a \" in front of each quote with no luck.  I think I need to use the eval command but I'm not sure.  Any ideas on what needs to be done?  Here is the latest change I've made:

```
eval ssh root@linux \""cd /submittals;gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/submittals/012606-003e.pdf -c \""<</BeginPage{0.9 0.9 scale 30.6 39.6 translate}>> setpagedevice\"" -sPAPERSIZE=letter -dCompatibilityLevel=\""1.3\"" -dPDFSETTINGS=\""/printer\"" -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -f /submittals/012606-003b.pdf\""
```

Comment: I couldn't get why you have to use `eval` in your script. Could you explain more precisely?

Comment: I'm not sure that I have to.  If you have a way to make it work, please let me know.

Comment: what happens if you just execute `gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q ....` ?

Comment: if I do that it works just fine...it's the second command (using eval) that I'm having trouble with

Answer (score 0):

eval is unnecessary and unhelpful (in this case), because it adds an extra layer of dequoting to your problem.

```
ssh root@linux "cd /submittals;gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/submittals/012606-003e.pdf -c \"<</BeginPage{0.9 0.9 scale 30.6 39.6 translate}>> setpagedevice\" -sPAPERSIZE=letter -dCompatibilityLevel=\"1.3\" -dPDFSETTINGS=\"/printer\" -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -f /submittals/012606-003b.pdf"
```

I haven't tested this, but by eye it looks right.

Comment: Actually, you could get away without most of the escaped quotes in the command too...  E.g. -dCompatibilityLevel=\"1.3\" and -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 will work identically.